# Javascript loads wrong on specific page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This will be a newbie question, but i hope that there is a gentle soul which knows how to handle the following problem.

I got two almost identical pages - except for very small changes on each page. Nothing i can see that should affect how the page is handled. On one page, everythings loads as it should. On the other page, 1 out of 4 times, the js does not load at all.

The pages are in Wordpress.

I have tried everything i know. The default.js are identical for the page, the function.php are identical for the page. I simple do not know how to figure out what is wrong and how to debug it. As the code is identical, i see no reason to post the code - as it works on one page, but not the other. So to my knowledge, something else must be wrong, but i have no idea what.

The two pages are http://dev.ateo.dk/kollekolle/ and http://copy.ateo.dk/kollekolle/ . copy.ateo.dk is the one that is **not** working The js is loaded if the tabs works. Try re-fresh to encounter the problem.

Cheers.

Comment: You have reference errors on both pages. 1: `$ is not defined` and 2: `jQuery is not defined`. Check the console in your favorite browser's development tools (although both seemed to have worked for me in Chrome).

Comment: Which browser you are looking at to get the error?

Comment: @vishwanath - I am using the newest version of Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems like the one you describe are often hard to track down, and can be specific to certain browsers, or even specific versions of browsers. It's why websites like www.caniuse.com are so useful.

Specifically about your problem: I don't think the following 2 errors help.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/js/default.js:5
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/js/jquery.cookie.js:17
```

It appears your jQuery isn't loaded in properly in some (or all) cases. When you fix that your problem might also go away.

P.S. This error comes from the Developer Console on the latest version of Chrome.

EDIT: It seems that jQuery is not loaded in yet by the time your default.js starts to execute. Try and find where both jQuery and your default.js are supposedly loaded in, and see if you can make sure that it happens in the right order (for example, placing a `<script src="..."></script>` first for jQuery and **directly** below that for your default.js should make sure your default.js cannot be loaded in before jQuery.

An extra issue could be if your default.js starts execution before the DOM is finished loading. In that case things like event handlers (for your tabs for example) might not be attached as expected (since the nodes to attach them to don't exist yet at the time of execution). This can be subtle, as it won't show any errors to indicate this is happening. Make sure you wait for a `$().load()` or equivalent before you start manipulating things script-wise.